# How to Create a list from Check boxes in user forms?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am making a program that is a grocery shopping list where the user will click the checkboxes and insert a quantity for each item.  The program will calculate the cost and if the cost is less than the budget I want it to create a list with the item and the amounts.  How do I get the list to appear on a worksheet?

Here is the code for the cost and budget:

```
Private Sub Begin_Click()
    Dim FoodCost As Double
    Dim Max As Double

    Max = CDbl(Budget)

Try:
    If Budget.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You must enter a budget for your shopping list")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FoodCost = 0
        If TP.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (5 * CDbl(TPquantity))
        If Toothpaste.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (3 * CDbl(ToothpasteQuantity))
        If Shampoo.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (7 * CDbl(shampooquantityQuantity))
        If Tomato.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (2 * CDbl(Tomatoquantity))
        If Lettuce.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (2 * CDbl(Lettucequantity))
        If Avocado.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (3 * CDbl(Avocadoquantity))
        If Tomato.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (2 * CDbl(Tomatoquantity))
        If Milk.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (6 * CDbl(MilkQuantity))
        If Orangjuice.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (7 * CDbl(OJquantity))
        If Beer.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (18 * CDbl(Beerquantity))
        If Pasta.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (3 * CDbl(Pastaquantity))
        If Cereal.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (6 * CDbl(Cerealquantity))
        If Popcorn.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (5 * CDbl(PopcornQuantity))
        If Chicken.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (12 * CDbl(Chickenquantity))
        If Turkey.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (8 * CDbl(TurkeyQuantity))
        If Salmon.Value = True Then FoodCost = FoodCost + (15 * CDbl(SalmonQuantity))
        Cost.Value = Format(FoodCost, "$#,##0.00")
        End If
        If Cost.Value > Max.Value Then
                GoTo Catch
        End If

Catch:
      MsgBox ("You are over budget, please remove some items or change budget")
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

This is the user form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your picture so this is best guess, and assumes you run this from the form

```
Sub Make_List()
dim r as range
set r = activesheet.range("a1")   'or wherever you want it
Dim c as control
for each c in me.controls
    if instr(c.name,"quantity")>0 then
          r=me.controls(replace(c.name,"quantity","")).text
          r.offset(0,1)=c
          set r = r.offset(1,0)
    end if
next c
end sub
```

Code not tested but it ought to be close